# Session management for unauthenticated users

Tags: session, django-models, forms-authentication

I have a strange question about session management.

I implemented a form chain and after forms are completed a model is saved to database but that model has fields like `create_user`, `update_user` and so on.

In order to fill these `user` fields,of course, there should be an authenticated user.However, my form chain can be filled by anonymous user, as well.

If that anonymous user registers or logins to the system before his session flushs, his `user_id` should be assigned to  `create_user` and `update_user` fields..

What is the best way to implement such system ?

I hope I explain the situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your model is saved save the model instance to a list in your session, for example:

views.py:

```
...
form = DataForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save()
    instances = request.session.get('filed_instances', [])
    instances.append(instance)
    request.session['filed_instances'] = instances
```

in your login method after logging in (depends on your implementation offcourse) you can update these as follows:

```
instances = request.session.get('filed_instances')
if instances:
    for instance in instances:
        instance.create_user = request.user
        instance.update_user = request.user
        instance.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your logged in username in a session variable. At session start, if that variable is not set, set it to an empty string, null or any other value which represent to you an anonymous user. Than, when saving data in a database, use that name as creation/update username.
I hope it was helpful :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I forgot to mention that my create_user is referenced to user table. So I need to have a user object. I also consider such method, like null the create_user and after logged in check if there is a saved model in session then set its create_user to authenticated user. However, I am not sure its correctness...